# suspicious oauth2 implementation detail in facebook API

Tags: oauth, facebook

in RFC 6749 The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework

`2.3.1.  Client Password` definitely states that authentication at `TokenEndpoint` can be done in two alternate ways

1. HTTP basic authentication - client_id:client_secret
2. in the POST request-body, client_id={client_id}, client_secret={client_secret}

While Facebook API demands a Get request with URL encoded parameters:

```
    GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id={app-id}
    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &code={code-parameter}
```

Isn't this (non standard compliant way) exposing of client passwords in URL breaking security logic of AUTH2. And opening doors to vulnerabilities?

Comment: It's over HTTPS.  So I think everything should be cool.

Comment: IIRC, Facebook implemented OAuth 2.0 very early on, at something like v12 of the draft.  As the standard is something like v31, there will indeed be differences between their implementation and the final spec.

Comment: HTTPS, but not in body!
URL parameters are visibly sometimes: Servers Logs, Browser history.
I was sure sensitive data in URL should be excluded when possible. :)

Comment: you're right. that's an attack-vector, but not a critical one. could be avoided by using OAuth1 ;)